# Salesforce, Locker: Cannot "createObjectURL" using a unsecure [object File]

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm having some problem with a lightning component that was done by other developer that left the company, users are telling me that the tool was working perfectly 1 month ago but i don't have any idea of what is happening then
The error is :

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
> failed: c:EMB_CCW_Panel$controller$onPickFile [Locker: Cannot
> "createObjectURL" using a unsecure [object File]!] Failing descriptor:
> {c:EMB_CCW_Panel$controller$onPickFile}

and the javascript method is this one

```
onPickFile : function(component, event, helper) {
        var catalog = component.get("v.catalogWrapper");
        var brandsList = component.get("v.brandsList");

        console.log("onPickFile", catalog);
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);


        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', fileURL);
        req.onload = function() {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
            component.set("v.catalogWrapper",
                helper.fillCatalogWithXMLData(catalog, helper.extractSlideNotesFromODTContentXML(this.responseXML), brandsList));
        };
        req.onerror = function() {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
            console.log('Error loading XML file.');
        };
        req.send();
    },
```

and the helper methods,

```js
extractSlideNotesFromODTContentXML : function(xmlDoc){
        var output = [];
        var slides = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("draw:page");

        for(var s=0;s<slides.length;s++){
            var notes = slides[s].getElementsByTagName("presentation:notes")[0].getElementsByTagName("draw:frame")[0].getElementsByTagName("draw:text-box")[0].getElementsByTagName("text:p");

            var slideNotesList = [];
            for(var i =0;i<notes.length;i++){
                slideNotesList.push(notes[i].textContent);
            }
            output.push(slideNotesList);
        }
        return output;
    },

    fillCatalogWithXMLData : function(catalog, slidesList, brandsList){
        try {
            var referenceRegEX = /^(\d){9}/;

            for(var i=0;i<slidesList.length;i++){
                catalog.slides.splice(i, 0, this.generateSlideObject(i+1));


                for(var j=0;j<slidesList[i].length;j++){
                    var wholeLine = slidesList[i][j];
                    var firstWord = wholeLine.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase();
                console.log('firstWord', firstWord)
                    // Lines that begin with a number are references (SAP Id code). Consider the rest brand names:
                    if(referenceRegEX.test(firstWord) && firstWord.length == 9){
                        catalog.slides[i].referencesText += wholeLine+"\n";
                    }else{
                        // That's not a reference, check if it's a brand:
                        // 1.- Check if the whole line is a brand (removing leading and trailing spaces)
                        if(brandsList.includes(wholeLine.trim())){
                            // Found brand:
                            catalog.slides[i].brandsText += wholeLine + "\n";
                        }else{
                            // Not found, not recognized:
                            catalog.slides[i].unrecognizedText += wholeLine + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            component.set("v.catalogWrapper", catalog);
        } catch(err) {

        }
        return catalog;
    }
```

anyone can't help me or tell me how can i fixe it !
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it used to work 1 month ago it's probably something Salesforce patched in Summer release. No idea what (if anything) is unsecure in your code but sounds like you're hit by Lightning Locker Service. Do you get same result in different browsers?

See if it works if you knock back the API version of component to [version 39](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_ls_disable.htm). It's a hack but might be a temp relief while you figure out what to do.

This suggests File is supported all right: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer

Maybe you need to read the file's content different way, maybe you need to give up on parsing it with JavaScript and push to server-side apex? I don't know what your functionality is.

If you go to setup -> lightning components -> debug mode and enable for yourself it might help a bit. You will see more human-friendly code generated in browser's developer tools, debugging might be simpler. Lesson learned would be to pay more attention to release preview windows (from ~September 12th we can preview Winter'21 release, SF should publish blog post about it in 1-2 weeks)

This looks promising: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/245232/799
Maybe your code needs proper Aura accessors, `event.getSource().get("v.files")[0]` instead of `event.target.files[0]`. You really would have to debug it and experiment in browser's console, see what sticks.